# using private docker registry with swarm

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-registry

I have seen multiple discussions where "pulling images from private registry" is talked about in Swarm cluster and solution mentioned is to use "--with-registry-auth". But where does the auth needs to be created is not clear to me!